# Checking the array position

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing the program in which i am checking that if the array is balance or not like the array
`int a5[] = {2, 1, 4, 3}; // balance array because i got even number on even position so program return 1
int a5[] = {3, 1, 4, 3}; // un balance array because i got odd number on even position so program return 0`

This is my program which i am trying

```
int araay(int arg[], int length);
int main()
{

    int a6[] = {3, 3, 4, 4};
    int a7[] = {2, 2, 3, 4};
    int a8[] = {4, 1, 2, 3};
    int a9[] = {1, 1};
    araay (a7,sizeof(a7));

}

int araay (int arg[], int length)
{
    int sumEven = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=length; i=i+2)
    {
        if (arg[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            sumEven++;
        }
        else
            sumOdd++;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=length; i=i+2)
    {
        if (arg[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            sumEven++;
        }
        else
            sumOdd++;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

in return it always return me `00000` something like zero everytime

Comment: `araay` always return 0, what else do you expect ?

Comment: Your function contains "return 0" as its only return. Not surprised that it returns 0.

Comment: I want it to return me `0` if the whole array is unbalanced and `1` if the `whole` araay is `balanced`

Comment: and your code doesn't compile, your edit is invalid

Comment: `sizeof (a7)` is not what you expect... `sizeof (a7) / sizeof (*a7)` is the value you want.

Comment: i dont know how to put condition for return for my whole array

Comment: Use `std::array`. It has a proper `size` function.

Comment: Now i update my compiled code , and thanks chris

Comment: @RabiiKhalid What do you mean by "i dont know how to put condition for return for my whole array" you did use `if`,`else`, use it some more :)

Comment: @chris `araay (a7,std::size_t(a7));` like this ?

Comment: @RabiiKhalid, There's no `std::array` there. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size. Having a separate size parameter is just inviting errors such as the one in your posted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following may help: (http://ideone.com/NttqbY)

```
bool is_balanced(const std::vector<std::size_t>& v)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if ((i % 2) != (v[i] % 2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I done it on my own too but your answer is more accurate , thanks

Comment: its showing error on braces `std::cout << is_balanced({2, 1, 4, 3}) << std::endl;`

Comment: The link used C++11 to compile. If you use C++03, then you have to construct the vector the old way.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your comments and help

This is what i tried

```
int araay(int arg[], int length);
int main()
{

    int a6[] = {3, 3, 4, 4};
    int a7[] = {2, 3, 2, 3};
    int a8[] = {4, 1, 2, 3};
    int a9[] = {1, 1};
    araay (a7,3);


}

int araay (int arg[], int length)
{
    int sumEven = 0;
    int sumOdd = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=length; i+=2)
    {
        if (arg[i]%2 != 0)
        {
            cout<<"unbalanced"<<endl;
        //  return 0;

        }
        else
        {
            sumEven++;
        }
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=length; i=i+2)
    {
        if (arg[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            cout<<"unbalanced"<<endl;
            sumEven++;
        }
        else
        {
            sumOdd++;
        //  return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but the answer of @jarod is looking more suitable and easy

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do

```
#include <iostream>

int check(int arg[])
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(arg); ++i)
    {
        if ((i % 2) != (arg[i] % 2))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int b[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int c[] = { 2, 2, 3, 3 };

    std::cout << "a = " << check(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << check(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << check(c) << std::endl;

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (arg)` is not what you expected (for several reasons (firstly, you have `sizeof (int*)`, and secondly, it would be `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` for an array)). So, it would be better to pass the size as parameter.

Comment: In this case sizeof(arg); works perfectly, try it yourself adding std::cout << sizeof(arg) << std::endl; Thanks ! :)

Comment: Try with an array of size != 4, as `sizeof (arg)` is `4` as your are in 32bit.